# Can I use hiera with a YAML backend to combine arrays?

Tags: arrays, yaml, hiera

I'm using hiera with a YAML backend to manage my Puppet configuration and I'd like to append some values to an array.

I have a configuration file which looks a bit like this:

```
---
some_config:
  - one
  - two
  - three

some_more_config:
  - one
  - two
  - three
  - four
```

Where `some_more_config` is always a superset of `some_config`.

I'd like to improve this file to remove the duplication but I haven't figured out whether it's possible or what the syntax would be:

```
---
some_config:
  - one
  - two
  - three

some_more_config:
  - "%{::some_config}"
  - four
```

In words rather than code, `some_more_config` is the entire contents of `some_config` plus one additional value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that in Hiera because it can only interpolate string-based information (numbers are converted to strings) and not arrays or hashes.

From the [Hiera 3: Interpolation Tokens, Variables, and Lookup Functions](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/3.0/variables.html):

> Hiera can interpolate values of any of Puppet’s data types, but the value will be converted to a string.

You can still do this via the Puppet DSL though. Here are a few options:

1. The [Hiera 3: Lookup Types](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/3.0/lookup_types.html) documentation covers this in detail, but if these were in multiple levels of the hierarchy you could merge them together using the `hiera_array()` method. Given how your hierarchy is set up, some hosts could get the smaller list, and some hosts could get the larger list.
2. The [puppetlabs-stdlib module](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib) can also help. It has [concat](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib#concat) and [union](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib#union) methods for arrays.